# Why is CGRect not treated as an object in terms of pointers?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Pointers vs non-pointers.  I understand the following:

```
NSString *string1 = @"This is first string";   //this is an object, requires pointers
int firstInt = 42;    //this doesn't require pointers
```

When referencing objects:

```
CGRect screenRect = self.window.bounds;
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect;
```

How come when calling CGRect it doesn't require a pointer? I'm pretty sure that it's an object as it has multiple instance variables. If it were an int, float I understand, but its  an object.

Comment: No, CGRect is not an object, it's a structure.

Comment: Would it be correct to state that CGRect behaves like an object in terms of methods and instance variables? But stored like a C structure?

Comment: No, not really. A structure doesn't have any methods (there are methods that operate on CGRects though). It also doesn't have instance variables, it has fields. You can think of a struct as a group of variables, that are themselves either other structs (like origin and size in a CGRect), or C primitives (like floats, ints, char, etc.).

Comment: It is confusing.  But CGRect is a `struct`, meaning its behavior is halfway between object and "primitive".

Comment: This article might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html

Answer (score 2):

CGRect's are actually C Structure's, not objects so they don't require pointers.

Comment: A little confused.  int/float/double - Direct store, NSString - Object, CGRect - C Structure. I'm assuming that C structures are stored directly in memory then due to C architecture? Are there any other types which would require pointers, or directly store into memory?    Is int/float/double a C structure?

Comment: Int/float/doubles aren't c-structures they are just stored the same way. They are all stored sequentially in memory, here's more info about c-structs memory allocation http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment